# Hibernate MS SQL Join issue

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, left-join, table-relationships

I have two tables in the clients mssql database. The first is a job table - so I created an Job entity which contains the load type and load weight and all that stuff - works fine.

My problem now is that there is a second table that includes informations about the load and unload point. The second table, I call it JEP, has a primary key consisting of several items: the type (load or unload), the zip code and the customer number.

I created an entity JobEndPoint and NetBeans also created an object representing the primary key JobEndPointPK containing all that fields.

I want to add two JobEndPoint (loadPoint and unloadPoint) to my Job entity. My problem is now: how do I annotate that in Hibernate? In my opinion it is an @OneToOne relation ship. It would be perfect if I could specify a SELECT statement like `SELECT * FROM JEP WHERE type="load" AND customer_nr="123" AND zip_code="123` ...". Is that possible with Hibernate?

Thanks for your help!

Regeards,

Marco

---

Here are the Entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Auftragsdaten", catalog = "...", schema = "dbo")
public class Job implements Comparable<Object>, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4285871251915951149L;

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "`id`", nullable = false)
    int id;

    @Column(name = "`AufNr`", nullable=false)
    int jobId;

    @Transient
    List<Integer> jobsAdded;

    @Column(name = "`Beladedatum`", nullable=false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    Date loadDate;

    @Column(name = "`Beladezeit`")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
    Date loadTimeFrom;

    @Transient
    Date loadTimeTo;

    @Column(name = "`Entladedatum`", nullable=false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    Date unloadDate;

    @Column(name = "`Entladezeit Beginn`")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
    Date unloadTimeFrom;

    @Column(name = "`Entladezeit Ende`")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
    Date unloadTimeTo;

    @Transient
    List<JobEndPoint> froms;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumns ({
        @JoinColumn(name="`Beladetyp`", referencedColumnName = "`Ladetyp`", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name="`AbsNr`", referencedColumnName = "`KundenNr`", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name="`Verkehrsart`", referencedColumnName = "`VerkArt`", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name="`von LKZ`", referencedColumnName = "`LKZ`", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name="`von PLZ`", referencedColumnName = "`PLZ`", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    JobEndPoint fromPoint;

    @Transient
    JobEndPoint toPoint;

    @Column(name = "`Verkehrsart`", length = 10, nullable=false)
    @Enumerated
    JobType type;

    @Column(name = "`Anzahl Paletten CCG1`")
    int numberCCG1;

    @Column(name = "`Anzahl Paletten CCG2`")
    int numberCCG2;

    @Transient
    int numberFullContainer;

    @Transient
    int numberEmptyContainer;

    @Column(name = "`Anzahl Container`")
    int numberContainer;

    @Column(name = "`Anz Stellplätze`")
    int numberUnits;

    @Column(name = "`Bruttogewicht`", nullable=false)
    int loadWeight;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="`Kühlkennzeichen`")
    CoolingCode coolingCode;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "BES", catalog = "...", schema = "dbo")
public class JobEndPoint implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1017986852824783744L;

    @Id
    protected JobEndPointPK jobEndPointPK;

    (...)
}

@Embeddable
public class JobEndPointPK implements Serializable {

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "`Ladetyp`", nullable = false, length = 50)
    @Enumerated
    EndPointType type;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "`KundenNr`", nullable = false)
    int customerId;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "`VerkArt`", nullable = false, length = 10)
    @Enumerated
    JobType jobType;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "`LKZ`", nullable = false, length = 3)
    String countryCode;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "`PLZ`", nullable = false, length = 7)
    String zipCode;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, I would recommend using a generated internal primary key instead of the composite key. However, if you need to stick with your composite key, here are some ideas that hopefully help.

I understand that `JobEndPointPK` is implemented as an identifier component (see the Hibernate Reference, [chapter 8.4](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/components.html#components-compositeid)). Note: it is critical that it implements the `equals` and hashCode` methods correctly, as Hibernate relies on these.

**Updated:** Provided that your `JobEndPoint` and `JobEndPointPK` looks something like this:

```
@Embeddable
class JobEndPointPK {
    @Column(name = "type", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated
    EndPointType type;

    @Column(name = "zipCode", nullable = false)
    String zipCode;

    @Column(name = "customerNumber", nullable = false)
    int customerId;

    // equals, hasCode, getters, setters etc.
}

@Entity
class JobEndPoint {
    @Id
    private JobEndPointPK key;

    // getters, setters etc.
}
```

The mapping annotation would be something like:

```
@Entity
class Job {
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumns ({
        @JoinColumn(name="loadPointType", referencedColumnName = "type"),
        @JoinColumn(name="loadPointZip", referencedColumnName = "zipCode"),
        @JoinColumn(name="loadPointCust", referencedColumnName = "customerNumber")
    })
    private JobEndPoint loadPoint;
    // similarly for unloadPoint
    // other properties
}
```

The example is adapted from [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1700).

I am not sure how to deal with `JobEndPointPK.type` though, as for `loadPoint` it is obviously `Load` and for `unloadPoint`, `Unload`, so you most probably don't want to store it separately in the DB. My gues is that you can specify the value with the `@Formula` annotation, but I haven't seen any concrete example for this.

Note that all this code is purely experimental, I haven't tested it.

There are other variations on the theme. For more details, see the section "Composite keys with annotations" in [Chapter 8 of Java Persistence with Hibernate](http://www.theserverside.com/tt/articles/content/JavaPersistenceHibernate/JavaPersistenceHibernate_Chapter8.pdf).

Comment: Thanks! This looks like a start. Is it correct that I have the JobEndPointPK in the Job object although I want the JobEndPoint object ? Or the other way: how do I get the JobEndPoint object with the JobEndPointPK stored in the Job during runtime?

Comment: @Marco Damn, I messed it up :-( Now I updated the code. I also linked a better example.

Comment: Hi again. Thanks for sticking with me. I posted my entity declartions above and hope it will help...

Comment: If you leave out the condition loadtype (first @JoinColumn) Hibernate reports:
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(`KundenNr`, `VerkArt`, `LKZ`, `PLZ`) of Job.fromPoint referencing JobEndPoint not mapped to a single property

Comment: @Marco Now I am puzzled as to what your problem actually is. You do have `@JoinColumn(name="``von LKZ``", referencedColumnName = "``LKZ``", ...),` in your code, is that supposed to do filtering? Do you have column `LKZ` in your table? If so, is it mapped in `JobEndPointPK`?

Comment: Yes, I am puzzled, too. I double checked the spelling. "LKZ" is in the JobEndPointPK and in the table. This is why I don't understand the error message... Well, I need to filter. The table JobEndPoint has a primary key consisting of this 4 fields - all defined in JobEndPointPK. I am sorry that the database scheme is in German...

Comment: I get the same exception if I try to do an @ManyToOne instead of a @OnetoOne

Comment: @Marco What is `PLZ` then? Is it also a column in `JobEndPointPK`? And what is `name="von LKZ"`? I don't think you can have property names contain spaces... Also why are you putting the `@JoinColumn` attribute values between single backquotes (`)?

Comment: I put them between backquotes because they contain space characters. I thought this is the way in Hibernate to escape characters? "PLZ" is the zip code and "von LKZ" is the "from contry code". There is also a "from zip code" and a "to zip code" and so on... I have the problem that I cannot alter the database scheme, because the customer is already working with this...

Comment: @Marco Well, I really can't find any obvious mistake in what you did... :-( Could you post the `CREATE TABLE` SQL statements too?

Comment: @Peter: I removed the "`" in the cases they were not necessary and it worked! So - your solution was the right one. I still cannot figure out why and when you have to escape characters in the column name definition. Anyway - thanks for your help and advise in this matter!

Comment: @Marco Glad to hear you managed to make it work finally! AFAIK you should quote only when the column name contains whitespaces, strange characters, is case sensitive or conflicts with a reserved word. Now we learned a bit about the practical reason behind :-)